# Link doesn't work

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

maybe it's just silly question but I honestly can't wrap my head around what's going wrong here.

A site i'm building have 1 page contain of 2 wide container that each container also used for page, so it's like 2 page inside 1 page, the example just like this:

```
<div class="container1"><a name="page1"></a></div>
<div class="container2"><a name="page2"></a></div>
```

and the 'container2' a.k.a 'page2' floating to the right side from the 'page1'

i have the 'menu link' and 'anchor' to the each page, but it's doesn't work to 'page2'

```
<a href="#page1">page1 </a>
<a href="#page2">page2 </a>
```

Any thoughts on what I've done wrong here?

Comment: change to: <div class="container1"><a href="#page1">page1 </a></div>...

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work to 'page2'"? You click it and it doesn't bring 'page2' into view?

Comment: @alfasin the 'menu link' should be direct to the container(page), not otherwise

Comment: Can you please setup a demo at http://jsfiddle.net (or give a link to your site)? I'm not sure that I'm what I'm picturing is what you are talking about.

Answer (score -2):

Did you mean this:

```
<div class="container1"><a href="#page1">page1</a></div>
<div class="container2"><a href="#page2">page2</a></div>
```

this is wrong HTML syntax:

```
<a name="page1"></a>
```

Comment: Why is that wrong html syntax? It has been made obsolete in HTML5, but before that it was correct syntax for an anchor _target_ element that could then be linked to from another anchor with `href="#page1"` (or `href="somepage.htm#page1"`).

Comment: @nnnnnn page2 is floating to the right side from page1, and the 'menu link' doesn't bring 'page2' as you said